# onDestroy called before onActivityResult

Tags: android

I have this Activity A, 
On Button Click, It starts an activity for result which is a contact picker,
When this activity starts onPause of A is called,
When i return from the contact picker onDestroy of A is called somehow and onActivityResult is not at all called !!

Comment: please post the code you have written.

Comment: i removed the onDestroy fn from the code, and solved the issue :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, *onDestroy()* gets called when an activity is finished or removed from the backstack. I hope you are not calling *finish()* in A before or after you are calling *startActivityForResult(..)*.

Can you go back from B (the contact picker) by pressing the back button?

Comment: I had used a broadcast receiver in A which i unregistered in onDestroy , I removed the onDestroy and did the unregistering in onPause and now it works fine . Still no idea why !